# django rest framework: customize nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django model structure:

```
class TypeOfIngredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    typeofingredient = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfIngredient, related_name='typeof_ingredient',null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Serializer:

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
```

With the above serializer i see the following api output:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "adrak",
            "slug": "adrak",
            "typeofingredient": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "banana",
            "slug": "banana",
            "typeofingredient": 1
        },
```

How to get `"typeofingredient": "fruit"` where fruit is the name field of the typeofingredient. What i am getting is the id.

I tried nested:

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

Then i get the api output as:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "adrak",
            "slug": "adrak",
            "typeofingredient": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "banana",
            "slug": "banana",
            "typeofingredient": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "fruit",
                    "slug": "fruit"
            }
        },
```

Here is showing all the details of the typeofingredient. Rather than this can i have directly `"typeofingredient": "fruit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *serializers.ReadOnlyField*

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    typeofingredient = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='typeofingredient.name')    

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you guide me why we use ReadOnlyField. I am quite new to serializers

Comment: A field class that simply returns the value of the field without modification.
 [ReadOnlyField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can add **str** method on models.py

```
class TypeOfIngredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    typeofingredient = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfIngredient, related_name='typeof_ingredient',null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: this is not what the op want

Comment: he wants name instead of id... it returns the TypeOfIngredient name

Comment: well it may solve the problem but not a drf thing, it would be better to offer serializers approach

Comment: I am looking for serialzer approach